# (Nativescript) Cannot convert JavaScript object with id x at index 0 interface implementation

Tags: javascript, android, nativescript

I've been looking at other similar issues here and on github but failed to figure out a solution based on analogy, so maybe somebody here can help?

I'm trying to get the following plugin to work on Android:

```
var app = require("application");
var context = android.content.Context;
var TextToSpeech = android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
var initialised = false;
var tts;

var text_to_speech = {
    speak : function(text, queue, pitch, speakRate, volume){

        if(!tts || !initialised) {
            tts = new TextToSpeech(context, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener({
                onInit : function(status) {
                    // some code here
                }
            }));
        }
    }
};
```

Unfortunately I'm getting an exception when initializing the tts object:

```
    JS: ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
JS: Error: Cannot convert JavaScript object with id 683715827 at index 0
JS:     at Error (native)
JS:     at Object.text_to_speech.speak (/data/data/org.nativescript.CzystyDywan/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-texttospeech/texttospeech.js:20:10)
JS:     at TextToSpeech.speakText (/data/data/org.nativescript.CzystyDywan/files/app/pages/texttospeech/texttospeech.component.js:9:13)
JS:     at DebugAppView._View_TextToSpeech0._handle_tap_4_0 (TextToSpeech.template.js:148:28)
JS:     at Object.<anonymous> (/data/data/org.nativescript.CzystyDywan/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:316:24)
JS:     at ZoneDelegate.invoke (/data/data/org.nativescript.CzystyDywan/files/app/tns_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:281:29)
JS:     at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvoke (/data/data/org.nativescript.CzystyDywan/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/src/zone/ng_zone_impl.js:45:41)
JS:     at ZoneDelegate.invoke (/data/data/org.nativescript.CzystyDywan/files/app/tns_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:280:35)
JS:     at Zone.runGuarded (/data/data/org.nativescript.CzystyDywan/files/app/tns_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:188:48)
JS:     at Object.callback (/data/data/org.nativescript.CzystyDywan/files/app/tns_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:164:30)
JS: ERROR CONTEXT:
JS: [object Object]
W/System.err( 3701):    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
W/System.err( 3701):    at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:861)
W/System.err( 3701):    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:726)
W/System.err( 3701):    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:712)
W/System.err( 3701):    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:693)
W/System.err( 3701):    at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:683)
```

I understand that this has something to do with the implementation of the TextToSpeech.OnInitListener interface but I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Anybody has had similar problems and can share some hints? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I was actually constructing the tts object wrong – instead of using app.android.context I was using android.content.Context to get the context for the constructor. This is because I was getting "undefined" for the former. Now I'm using this helper function to get the current context:

```
function _getContext() {
    if (appModule.android.context) {
        return (appModule.android.context);
    }
    var ctx = java.lang.Class.forName("android.app.AppGlobals").getMethod("getInitialApplication", null).invoke(null, null);
    if (ctx) return ctx;

    ctx = java.lang.Class.forName("android.app.ActivityThread").getMethod("currentApplication", null).invoke(null, null);
    return ctx;
}
```